# I try to make a cascade of combo boxes (4 combo boxes) to filter the information and see only the appropriate result

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I try to make a cascade of combo boxes (4 combo boxes) to filter the information and see only the appropriate result. I practically don't know from this point how to declare and how to use the information I have, I have some code but I have no results... all of the combo are empty.

I find solution on how to add the code separately in the combo but I try to have a dynamic filtering as the criteria is change the results.

```
Private Sub Ctl1_Click()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rec As Recordset
    Dim AreaFromV As String
    Dim AreaToV As String
    Dim PolV As String
    Dim PodV As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strSQLc1 As String
    Dim strSQLc2 As String
    Dim strSQLc3 As String
    Dim strSQLc4 As String



    strSQLc1 = "SELECT DISTINCT Seafreights.[Area From]"
    strSQLc1 = strSQLc1 & "FROM Seafreights"
    strSQLc1 = strSQLc1 & "ORDER BY Seafreights.[Area From];"

    If IsNull(strSQLc1) Then
        AreaFromV = 0
        Me.Requery
        Me.[1].RowSource = ""
        Me.[1].RowSource = AreaFromV
    Else
        AreaFromV = strSQLc1
        [Forms]![pricelist]![1].RowSource = AreaFromV
        Me.Requery
        Me.[1].RowSource = ""
        Me.[1].RowSource = AreaFromV
    End If



    'AreaFromV = IIf([Forms]![pricelist]![1] Is Null, 0, [Forms]![pricelist]![1])

    strSQLc2 = "SELECT DISTINCT Seafreights.[Area To], Seafreights.[Area From]"
    strSQLc2 = strSQLc2 & "FROM Seafreights"
    strSQLc2 = strSQLc2 & "WHERE(((Seafreights.[Area From]) = AreaFromV))"
    strSQLc2 = strSQLc2 & "ORDER BY Seafreights.[Area To];"

    If IsNull(strSQLc2) Then
        AreaToV = 0
        Me.Requery
    Else
        AreaToV = strSQLc2
        [Forms]![pricelist]![2].RowSource = AreaToV
        Me.Requery
    End If

    'AreaToV = IIf([Forms]![SeaFreight]![2] Is Null, [Forms]![SeaFreight]![2], 0)

    strSQLc3 = "SELECT DISTINCT Seafreights.[Port of Loading], Seafreights.[Area From]"
    strSQLc3 = strSQLc3 & "FROM Seafreights"
    strSQLc3 = strSQLc3 & "WHERE(((Seafreights.[Area From]) = AreaToV))"
    strSQLc3 = strSQLc3 & "ORDER BY Seafreights.[Port of Loading];"

    If IsNull(strSQLc3) Then
        PolV = 0
        Me.Requery
    Else
        PolV = strSQLc3
        [Forms]![pricelist]![3].RowSource = PolV
        Me.Requery
    End If


    'PolV = IIf([Forms]![SeaFreight]![3] Is Null, [Forms]![SeaFreight]![3], 0)

    strSQLc4 = "SELECT DISTINCT Seafreights.[Port of Discharge], Seafreights.[Area To] "
    strSQLc4 = strSQLc4 & "FROM Seafreights"
    strSQLc4 = strSQLc4 & "WHERE(((Seafreights.[Area To]) = AreaToV))"
    strSQLc4 = strSQLc4 & "ORDER BY Seafreights.[Port of Discharge];"

    If IsNull(strSQLc4) Then
        PodV = 0
        Me.Requery
    Else
        PodV = strSQLc4
        [Forms]![pricelist]![4].RowSource = PodV
        Me.Requery
    End If

    'PodV = IIf([Forms]![SeaFreight]![4] Is Null, [Forms]![SeaFreight]![4], 0)

    strSQL = "SELECT Seafreights.[Area From], " & _
            "Seafreights.[Area To]," & _
            "Seafreights.[Port of Loading]," & _
            "Seafreights.[Port of Loading Locodes]," & _
            "Seafreights.[Port of Discharge]," & _
            "Seafreights.[Port of Discharge Locodes], " & _
            "Seafreights.Commodity, " & _
            "Seafreights.Curr, " & _
            "Seafreights.[20'STD], " & _
            "Seafreights.[40'STD/HC], " & _
            "Seafreights.Effective, " & _
            "Seafreights.Expiration, " & _
            "Seafreights.[Not Subject To], " & _
            "Seafreights.[Subject to Contract  (see Sheets Arbitraries + Inlands and Surch], Seafreights.[Subject to Tariff Charges], " & _
            "Seafreights.[GEO from], " & _
            "Seafreights.[GEO To], " & _
            "Seafreights.[Amend- ment #], " & _
            "Seafreights.[Owner Sales Hierarchy], " & _
            "Seafreights.[SVC ID]"

    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM Seafreights "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (((Seafreights.[Area From])= AreaFromV) " & _
            "AND ((Seafreights.[Area To])= AreaToV) " & _
            "AND ((Seafreights.[Port of Loading])= polv) " & _
            "AND ((Seafreights.[Port of Discharge])= podv)) "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY Seafreights.[Area From], Seafreights.[Area To], Seafreights.[Port of Loading], Seafreights.[Port of Discharge];"


End Sub
```

Comment: OK, so what is your question then?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the beginning and step through the code in the debugger. Pay attention to what the concatenated `strSQLc1` to `strSQLc4` and `strSQL` look like. Also, you don't seem to use those strings to actually query the db. No wonder, you don't see any result.

Comment: as always it would help if you posted your data and the results you want.  Usually you want to combine all criteria into one long filter.  for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567394/dynamically-coding-filters-on-access-form

Comment: Use of AreaToV and AreaFromV and polv and podv in query statements makes no sense. Setting a RowSource to these variables also makes no sense. Constructed strSQL is never used anywhere. Your code is not 'cascading' comboboxes. Cascading requires code behind each combobox to set its RowSource based on selection in a previous combobox. All your code is one procedure.

Answer (score 0):

String variables cannot hold null so testing for null is meaningless and the True condition will never process. Test for empty string.

`If strSQLc1 = "" Then`

However, since code just set value of strSQLc1, there really is no need to even test if string is empty - it can never be empty. Same for the other SQL variables.

Need separator space at end of each continuation line for building strSQLc1 and strSQLc2 and strSQLc3 and strSQLc4 SQL statements:

```
    strSQLc1 = "SELECT DISTINCT Seafreights.[Area From] "
    strSQLc1 = strSQLc1 & "FROM Seafreights "
    strSQLc1 = strSQLc1 & "ORDER BY Seafreights.[Area From];"
```

Also need space after "Seafreights.[SVC ID]" for strSQL: `"Seafreights.[SVC ID] "`

For cascading comboboxes, place code in combobox events to set their RowSource based on value selected in another combobox. Use AfterUpdate and/or GotFocus events.

Then you need code behind button that uses combobox selections to build filter criteria for applying to form or report.

Both cascading comboboxes and using VBA to build dynamic filter criteria are common topics.
[Cascading Combo Boxes - Dependent Box is Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611469/cascading-combo-boxes-dependent-box-is-blank)
[how to show query results in a datasheet in the same form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827047/how-to-show-query-results-in-a-datasheet-in-the-same-form)